# Running dotnet core application (dll) without SDK

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to get my dotnet Core application running on an ubuntu 18.04LTS machine with dotnet core runtime installed.

The command:

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

The result:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

As far as I understand I do not need the SDK for simply running this application. Just the runtime should suffice, right?

```
dotnet --info
```

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.8
  Commit:  b9aa1abc51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

How to make this work without installing an SDK?

Comment: Hi Matthijs, how did you release your app? Did you use: `publish -c release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64`

Comment: A colleague actually did the build. He used Visual Studio on windows. He's unreachable atm. I did find a `myapp.runtimeconfig.json` file if that helps?
`{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.2",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "2.2.0"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: The runtime config doesn't show whether the app was compiled for Windows or Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

It actually worked. I was running the `dotnet` command with the wrong path.. `myapp.dll` was nested a bit deeper. My mistake.